# БД сама добавляет &amp; (барабашка)

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, функции, phpmyadmin

Есть вот такая строка:

```
2854693asdrvbh!)>%&#^"<dff\:'-=~
```

Перед записью в базу прогоняю эту строку через функцию:

```
function prep_data($m, $p) {
    $a = trim($p);
    $a = mysqli_real_escape_string($m, $a);
    $a = quotemeta($a);
    $a = htmlentities($a, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    return $a;
}
$str = prep_data($mysqli, "2854693asdrvbh!)%&#^"dff\:'-=~");
```

После прохода через функцию строка имеет такой вид в var_dump():

```
2854693asdrvbh!\)%&#\^\\"dff\\\\:\\'-=~
```

И в таком вот виде я отправляю эту строку в базу данных таким вот способом:

```
function add($p1) {
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES(?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "s", $p1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
}
add("2854693asdrvbh!\)%&#\^\\"dff\\\\:\\'-=~");
```

И в итоге в базе имеется запись этой строки в таком вот виде:

```
2854693asdrvbh!\)%&amp;#\^\\&quot;dff\\\\:\\&#039;-=~
```

Как видим запись произошла с дополнительной заменой амперсандов

```
//это 
&
//поменялось на это 
&amp;
```

Где зарыт барабашка и как от этого избавиться или что делать вообще подскажите пожалуйста?

Требуется, чтобы строка сохранялась в базу в том виде, как после функции, без доп замены амперсандов.

Comment: Не надо гнать на MySQL, ему в голову не придёт заниматься подобной ерундой. Это PHP. Включи General Log на MySQL и посмотри на текст запроса, который пришёл на сервер от PHP...

Comment: 1) https://www.php.net/htmlentities - Преобразует все возможные символы в соответствующие HTML-сущности

Comment: Ты сам добавил htmlentities, да еще и 2 раза. Для чего не понятно. Внутри твоей функции prep_data должно быть только mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @Knyaz71, Собственно это и делает функция. Почему после фукнции уже с преобразованием в сущности в базе данных дополнительно уже у преобразованной сущности преобразуется амперсанд???

Comment: @РоманМорозов, два раза добавил htmlentities, потому что с одним ничего не преобразовывается, а с двумя всё как надо. Посмотри внимательно на результат после этой функции. Строка после неё и строка в базе не похожи.

Comment: У вас в `prep_data()` используется `htmlentities` внутри самой себя, вот и получается что `&` -> `&amp;` -> `&amp;amp;`

Comment: @РоманМорозов mysqli_real_escape_string только экранирует, т.е. подставляет обратный слэш к определённым символам. Но она ведь в сущность угловые скобки тегов например ведь не преобразует.

Comment: @Knyaz71 А почему тогда вар дамп мне показывает строку без изменений, если прогнать её один раз через htmlentities? Типа изменения есть, но мы их не видим?

Comment: Сейчас попробую рекомендации и посмотрим, что будет.

Comment: Проверь, например, через `CTRL+SHIFT+i`, скорее всего браузер отображает `&amp;` -> `&`

Comment: Исправил вопрос, поменял функцию. Ничего не изменилось. База всё равно живет своей жизнью и на амперсанд преобразует апмерсанд.

Comment: @Knyaz71 CTRL+SHIFT+i показывает всё как на странице.

Answer (score 0):

Я лично открыл для себя Америку с этим вопросом) Или я перегрелся)

Весь мой функционал расписанный в вопросе ВЕРНЫЙ.

Несмотря на то, что значения в базе лежат с дополнительной обработкой амперсандов, при сравнении строка после функции и строка из базы БУДУТ ВЕРНЫ (true, true, true!!!).